# list with doubleclick results - python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, double-click

The following code allows selecting different files of a tree-like scheme (`ttk.Treeview`) made with [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter). The `variable` output below provides the result of a certain operation that is done on each selected file:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview()
        self.treeview.pack()

        sobreitem1 = self.treeview.insert("", tk.END, text="A")
        item0_1 = self.treeview.insert(sobreitem1, tk.END, text="1")
        item1_1 = self.treeview.insert(sobreitem1, tk.END, text="2")
        item2_1 = self.treeview.insert(sobreitem1, tk.END, text="3")
        item3_1 = self.treeview.insert(sobreitem1, tk.END, text="4")

        self.treeview.bind("<Double-1>", self.OnDoubleClick)
        self.root.mainloop()



    def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
        item = self.treeview.selection()[0]

        import operacion
        variable = operacion.calculo(item)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

My existential doubt is how to accumulate all those results of `variable` in a list, to be able to later use the set of all the selections made with a double-click?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Simply define an attribute storing an empty list, then append each item selected by double click. Here is the code skeleton:

```
...
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.variables = []
    ...

def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
    ...
    self.variables.append(operacion.calculo(item))
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add a list attribute to your `App` object by adding:

```
self.variable = list() # or []
```

inside `__init__` in order to have access to the value in the scope the object exists.

Then modify `OnDoubleClick` in order to *append*(as opposed to assigning) to the newly used `self.variable`. Replace:

```
variable = operacion.calculo(item)
```

with:

```
self.variable.append(operacion.calculo(item))
```